# Uploading a file with AJAX, Python, and CGI

Tags: python, ajax, python-3.x, file-upload, cgi

I'm having a very odd problem uploading an image with Python and AJAX. If I don't use AJAX, it works perfectly, but if I don't, I get a:

> ValueError: Invalid boundary in multipart form: b''

Note that I would like to do this without an iFrame, which according to [this post](https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/2.2.1/org.tizen.web.appprogramming/html/tutorials/w3c_tutorial/comm_tutorial/upload_ajax.htm) and [this Mozilla post](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Using_FormData_Objects) is possible.

The AJAX (Condensed)

```
var formData = new FormData()
formData.append("upload", form.upload.files[0]);

var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();

xmlhttp.open("POST","/cgi-bin/uploadPic.py", true);

xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","multipart/form-data");

xmlhttp.send(formData);
```

The HTML input field:

```
<input type="file" id="upload" name="upload" />
```

Relative Python:

```
import cgi
# This is where it fails
POST = cgi.FieldStorage()
```

I believe that should be enough to reproduce, if it's not, let me know.

Below are also some of the headers that differ, which I got from FF Live Headers.

> **Working:** Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------83059728161
> **Not Working:** Content-Type: multipart/form-data
>
> **Working:** Content-Length: 575804
> **Not Working:** Content-Length: 575810
>
> **Working:** [None]
> **Not Working:** Pragma: no-cache
>
> **Working:** Cache-Control: max-age=0
> **Not Working:** Cache-Control: no-cache
>
> **Working:** Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
> **Not Working:** Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=98
>
> **Working:** Transfer-Encoding: chunked
> **Not Working:** [None]

Everything else seems to be the same.

Comment: @Kermani, is there really no way to do it without an iframe? [This post](https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/2.2.1/org.tizen.web.appprogramming/html/tutorials/w3c_tutorial/comm_tutorial/upload_ajax.htm) seems to indicate that you can.

Comment: I get an error to open the page :"Object not found" , The link is not valid

Comment: Try again? Works when I click the link.

Comment: @Kermani, [here is a link from Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Using_FormData_Objects) stating the same thing. It should be with the FormData object. Also, if you'll notice, the difference between the content-length in the working and non working is 6 bytes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after reading some of the documentation on [Mozilla's page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Using_FormData_Objects), I found the solution.

You don't want to declare the `Content-type`, and just pass the entire form to FormData

After these lines:

```
formData.append("upload", form.upload.files[0]);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","multipart/form-data");
```

And all I'm left with is this:

```
// Note that form is now passed into FormData
var formData = new FormData(form)

var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();

xmlhttp.open("POST","/cgi-bin/uploadPic.py", true);

xmlhttp.send(formData);
```

Works in Chrome, FF, IE10, and IE11 (`FormData` is IE10+). I'm assuming it will work in Opera and Safari, since they are both Gecko based.